# Localizing the current date in python

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime, localization, format

This may sound dumb, but I'm trying to localize the current date with a four-digit year.
I know that datetime.strftime('%x') will do the locale part, but it returns a two-digit date (at least for en_US, ie. '07/06/23') but I want the year to be four-digit (ie. '07/06/2023').
So far, I've found I can either:

1. Use a string (%m/%d/%Y) to get a four-digit year in en_US locale, but that is ONLY for en_US and would have to be changed by a user with a different locale in a settings file (yay imperial measurements... stupid Americans... /s)
   So a user of my program in, say, the UK would need to change the format string to '%Y.%m.%d' in order to get the date in their preferred format.
2. Use a locale-agnostic string (%x) to get a date in the user's locale (which I believe will return a four-digit year for anyone using the metric system, b/c ya know, everyone else gets it...)
   but again, this returns a two-digit date for en_US.
   Basically, I want to have my cake and eat it too. Any ideas? Or should I just give up and accept a two-digit year for en_US?

I have tried using everything I can find in both 'datetime' and 'dateutils'.

Comment: just a minor remark, `%Y` will *always* give you a 4-digit year, not just for a specific locale (same for `%y` => 2-digit year).